# This sentence is a paradox to me. Is it correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

> This story is like a paradox in itself, revolves around the concepts of life and death, freedom and obligation; concludes with a final metaphor ”being locked inside a little box with no way out.”

I wanted to put 'and concludes' but too many *and*s didn't like it.

I don't want to separate them.

Comment: I think the question, in referring to "too many *ands*", goes beyond a "request for proofreading". OP is asking  how to put the clauses together.

Comment: I think this question's asking for proofreading, isn't it?

Comment: Welcome to ELL Nightray - you may want to look over the [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/) post on [meta] and [How can I write a better title for my ELL question?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2630/9161). Making it easy to understand what your exact question is will make it less likely that people will vote to close your question because they misunderstood it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sentence, if it is judged strictly and not granted the freedoms allowed to literary prose, is not perfectly grammatical. The clause that begins with **revolves** could be made into a participle clause, **revolving around...**

> This story is like a paradox in itself, **revolving** around the concepts
>   of life and death, freedom and obligation; **it** concludes with a final
>   metaphor **of** being locked inside a little box with no way out.

You could eliminate the semi-colon which requires you to make **concludes** the main verb, so you have to eliminate **is**:

> This story, a paradox in itself, **revolving** around the concepts
>   of life and death, freedom and obligation, concludes with a final
>   metaphor **of** being locked inside a little box with no way out.

You could also make the clause that begins with **concludes** a participle clause in parallel with the first one that begins with **revolving**:

> This story is like a paradox in itself, **revolving** around the concepts
>   of life and death, freedom and obligation, **and concluding** with a final
>   metaphor **of** being locked inside a little box with no way out.

Comment: Thank you very much really. I know 'and' is not the only problem. Maybe it's not even a problem. This is the first time, i'm asking something here. Sorry if i said anything wrong. But really thank you so much.

Comment: @Nightray:  You're welcome. BTW, your question received a couple of votes to be closed (not from me) because other users felt it was a "request for proofreading", which is not allowed on this site.  I think you avoided that problem by asking about how the clauses could be put together.

Answer (score 0):

Change the punctuation and grammar a bit for these two options:

This story is like a paradox in itself: revolving around the concepts of life and death, freedom and obligation; concluding with a final metaphor—"being locked inside a little box with no way out."

This story is like a paradox in itself. It revolves around the concepts of life and death, freedom and obligation; and concludes with a final metaphor: "being locked inside a little box with no way out."

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, I wrote the sentence as the second option before, but I wanted to connect them, then I couldn't remember the rest, I thought that it must be -ing, I don't know somehow I messed it up, got confused. "being locked inside a little box with no way out." is a sentence from the book. It needed more emphasis. Thanks for the clarification again.